# Two utterly different JAXB annotated classes, same @XmlElement name. Possible?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We have an existing document tree. We want to wrap some of the elements inside this tree up within a  element.

Depending on where in the tree we are, the  element will hold very different content.

So I have a DocumentPromptLanguage class and a DocumentRouterLanguage class. They have different parents and different children but it makes sense that in XML they are both called `<language>`.

Is this possible without adapters or must the XML representation disambiguate by element name?

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
    <info>
        <language>
            <iso639>en</iso639>
            <value>This is a sample document</value>
        </language>
        <language>
            <iso639>es</iso639>
            <value>Se trata de un documento de muestra</value>
        </language>
    </info>
    <someElement>
        <route>
            <language>
                <iso639>en</iso639>
                <possibleValues>Yes|No|Maybe</possibleValues>
                <prefix>For</prefix>
            </language>
            <language>
                <iso639>es</iso639>
                <possibleValues>sí|not|tal vez</possibleValues>
                <prefix>para</prefix>
            </language>
            <when>Tuesday</when>
            <afterTime>17.30</afterTime>
            <goto></goto>
        </route>
    </someElement>
</doc>
```

Comment: Could you post a sample XML doc?

Comment: I think that for clarity you should probably consider putting the different `<language>` elements in different namespaces regardless of whether it's possible or not to make this work. Actually, to me it doesn't make sense to call the `<language>` under `<info>` language. It's more a message or something like that than a language as it seems to just be a wrapper around a string and the language the string is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the class mapped to the `route` element can have a property mapped with `@XmlElement(name="language")`, and so can the class mapped to the `info` element. This because the mappings are scoped by class.